# Css style to an XML Node based on value from adjacent sibling Node

Tags: css, xml, css-selectors, xml-parsing

I want to change font-size, color etc of a node value based on another node value, In the below example, the font-styles need to be changed for name if touched >0 & not empty

```
<!DOCTYPE planet>
<planet>

<ocean>
<name>Arctic</name>
<area>13,000</area>
<depth>1,200</depth>
<touched>0</touched>
</ocean>

<ocean>
<name>Atlantic</name>
<area>87,000</area>
<depth>3,900</depth>
<touched>7</touched>
</ocean>
    
</planet>
```

I tried to use these for Css:

```
  ocean[touched]
    {
     font-size:25px;  
     display:block;  
     color: blue;  
     margin-left: 50px; 
    }
```

&

```
 ocean:has(touched:!empty) {
  display: block;
  margin: 2em 1em;
  border: 4px solid #cdf;
  padding: 0px 1em;
  background-color: white;
  }
```

Comment: Might be here a xlst job at first to match a template from which style can be set.

Comment: You probably can't do it exclusively with css selectors. You would have to use xpath.

Comment: What @G-Cyrillus said - use XSLT.